# Python node init equivalent

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pypi

Is there something similar to `node init` in python? something that would help initialize a python package with setup.py and proper package directories...

I saw a pypi library called `pip-init` but it hasn't been updated in years and doesn't work.

Comment: https://python-poetry.org/

Comment: Please read the documentation that was linked and you will see that it is an option. There are other options, but formally we don't do recommendations for third-party libraries here. Because of that, this is really a [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) question that is best handled [with a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=set+up+new+python+project+for+pip).

Comment: Poetry is a good choice for what you want to do. Cookiecutter is another that will likely get you farther than poetry. EG: https://github.com/ionelmc/cookiecutter-pylibrary See also https://github.com/topics/cookiecutter-template